# Auth controller not found

Tags: laravel

I did not find deafult AuthController when i build a project in laravel why? There are four other controllers forgotPasswordController, LoginController,RegisterController, ResetPasswordController why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan make:auth` will create AuthController controller and views in 5.2.

In 5.3 it will generate LoginController and RegisterController which are doing the same thing as AuthController in 5.2.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: thank u i did go through the internet. But couldn't find this